# search through ul > li > ul > li elements and highlight them if they contain an input str

Tags: jquery, list, loops, search

basically I have a sidebar organised by a list of lists, and I need to search only through the containts of the second order .
I don't know how to get my loop through all these lists.

**EDIT**

Reposted my question here :

[Getting the jquery right to do a search in lists and sublists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24952587/getting-the-jquery-right-to-do-a-search-in-lists-and-sublists)

Comment: if they contein *what* ?

Comment: Can you be more specific of what you want exactly?

Comment: please share your code

Comment: Because your reposted question contains more information, I voted to close this question as duplicate of the repost, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24952587/getting-the-jquery-right-to-do-a-search-in-lists-and-sublists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `:contains()` selector for that. Then you dont have to loop through each element to highlight them,

```
$("ul li:contains('Your text')").css("color","red");
```

Comment: I like that, it's nice and short. I wonder what the performance on that selector is.. Good Answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
function GetItemsContaining(elemContainer, sTargetString)
{
    // filter down by custom function
    return elemContainer.filter(function(index, elem)
    {
       return $(elem).text().indexOf(sTargetString) > -1;
    });

    // find them directly using only selectors
    return elemContainer.find("li:contains(" + sTargetString + ")");

    // or find the li in the container and filter down
    return elemContainer.find("li").filter(":contains(" + sTargetString + ")");

    // or find descendants that match the selector from the container
    return elemContainer.has("li:contains(" + sTargetString + ")");
}
```

Usage example :

```
var Items = GetItemsContaining($("#sidebar"), "Test String - Is case sensitive")
Items.addClasS("Highlight");
```

*If anyone has performance details for these methods handy, I would greatly appreciate an edit!*